# in PhpStorm version 2019.2.4, I get error in class name

Tags: php

in phpstrom version 2019.2.4, I get an error in class name. I couldn't understand why. my class is called fn. can someone with information help? thanks.

```
class fn{
  .....
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to create a class name of `test2` otherwise change file name to `fn`

Comment: `fn` is a reserved word (at least in PHP 7.4 where they introduce [the arrow functions/short closures](https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-74#arrow-functions-rfc)).

Comment: Thank you, Magnus Eriksson. Now I guess I'll have to revise my entire source code.  Can I ask the PhpStorm editor to ignore this ? do you think there is such a setting ?

Comment: You could probably change what PHP version PHPStorm uses for linting. However, that would be a _bad_ idea. Why would you knowingly write code you know won't work in the latest version of PHP? That's called a technical debt (which you don't want) since you will need to rewrite your code when you upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: my old projects are running in php5. 6. I don't want to revise it because I won't carry it. of course I will write my new projects in accordance with php7.4. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fn is a reserved word since PHP 7.4 and you should avoid it in a class naming. But if you insist, PHPStorm move to File -> Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> PHP -> PHP language level (set one of previous PHP versions).